# FMA instruction showing up as three packed double operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, intrinsics, perf

I'm analyzing a piece of linear algebra code which is [calling intrinsics directly](https://github.com/giaf/blasfeo/blob/bb298647843ead4ff484c41caab42a21e9896c3c/blasfeo_api/d_blas1_lib4.c#L378), e.g.

```
v_dot0  = _mm256_fmadd_pd( v_x0, v_y0, v_dot0 );
```

My test script computes the dot product of two double precision vectors of length 4 (so only one call to `_mm256_fmadd_pd` needed), repeated 1 billion times. When I count the number of operations with `perf` I get something as follows:

```
Performance counter stats for './main':

             0      r5380c7 (skl::FP_ARITH:512B_PACKED_SINGLE)                                                      (49.99%)
             0      r5340c7 (skl::FP_ARITH:512B_PACKED_DOUBLE)                                                      (49.99%)
             0      r5320c7 (skl::FP_ARITH:256B_PACKED_SINGLE)                                                      (49.99%)
 2'998'943'659      r5310c7 (skl::FP_ARITH:256B_PACKED_DOUBLE)                                                      (50.01%)
             0      r5308c7 (skl::FP_ARITH:128B_PACKED_SINGLE)                                                      (50.01%)
 1'999'928'140      r5304c7 (skl::FP_ARITH:128B_PACKED_DOUBLE)                                                      (50.01%)
             0      r5302c7 (skl::FP_ARITH:SCALAR_SINGLE)                                                           (50.01%)
 1'000'352'249      r5301c7 (skl::FP_ARITH:SCALAR_DOUBLE)                                                           (49.99%)
```

I was surprised that the number of `256B_PACKED_DOUBLE` operations is approx. 3 billion, instead of 1 billion, as this is an instruction from my architecture's instruction set. **Why does `perf` count 3 packed double operations per call to `_mm256_fmadd_pd`?**

Note: to test that the code is not calling other floating point operations accidentally, I commented out the call to the above mentioned intrinsic, and `perf` counts exactly zero `256B_PACKED_DOUBLE` operations, as expected.

*Edit: MCVE, as requested:*

`ddot.c`

```
#include <immintrin.h>  // AVX

double ddot(int m, double *x, double *y) {
    int ii;
    double dot = 0.0;

    __m128d u_dot0, u_x0, u_y0, u_tmp;
    __m256d v_dot0, v_dot1, v_x0, v_x1, v_y0, v_y1, v_tmp;

    v_dot0 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    v_dot1 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    u_dot0 = _mm_setzero_pd();

    ii = 0;

    for (; ii < m - 3; ii += 4) {
        v_x0 = _mm256_loadu_pd(&x[ii + 0]);
        v_y0 = _mm256_loadu_pd(&y[ii + 0]);
        v_dot0 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v_x0, v_y0, v_dot0);
    }
    // reduce
    v_dot0 = _mm256_add_pd(v_dot0, v_dot1);
    u_tmp = _mm_add_pd(_mm256_castpd256_pd128(v_dot0), _mm256_extractf128_pd(v_dot0, 0x1));
    u_tmp = _mm_hadd_pd(u_tmp, u_tmp);
    u_dot0 = _mm_add_sd(u_dot0, u_tmp);
    _mm_store_sd(&dot, u_dot0);
    return dot;
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double ddot(int, double *, double *);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    double x[4] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}, y[4] = {5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0};
    double xTy;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
        ddot(4, x, y);
    }
    printf(" %f\n", xTy);
    return 0;
}
```

I run `perf` as

```
sudo perf stat -e r5380c7 -e r5340c7 -e r5320c7 -e r5310c7 -e r5308c7 -e r5304c7 -e r5302c7 -e r5301c7 ./a.out
```

The disassembly of `ddot` looks as follows:

```
0000000000000790 <ddot>:
 790:   83 ff 03                cmp    $0x3,%edi
 793:   7e 6b                   jle    800 <ddot+0x70>
 795:   8d 4f fc                lea    -0x4(%rdi),%ecx
 798:   c5 e9 57 d2             vxorpd %xmm2,%xmm2,%xmm2
 79c:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 79e:   c1 e9 02                shr    $0x2,%ecx
 7a1:   48 83 c1 01             add    $0x1,%rcx
 7a5:   48 c1 e1 05             shl    $0x5,%rcx
 7a9:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
 7b0:   c5 f9 10 0c 06          vmovupd (%rsi,%rax,1),%xmm1
 7b5:   c5 f9 10 04 02          vmovupd (%rdx,%rax,1),%xmm0
 7ba:   c4 e3 75 18 4c 06 10    vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%rsi,%rax,1),%ymm1,%ymm1
 7c1:   01 
 7c2:   c4 e3 7d 18 44 02 10    vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%rdx,%rax,1),%ymm0,%ymm0
 7c9:   01 
 7ca:   48 83 c0 20             add    $0x20,%rax
 7ce:   48 39 c1                cmp    %rax,%rcx
 7d1:   c4 e2 f5 b8 d0          vfmadd231pd %ymm0,%ymm1,%ymm2
 7d6:   75 d8                   jne    7b0 <ddot+0x20>
 7d8:   c5 f9 57 c0             vxorpd %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
 7dc:   c5 ed 58 d0             vaddpd %ymm0,%ymm2,%ymm2
 7e0:   c4 e3 7d 19 d0 01       vextractf128 $0x1,%ymm2,%xmm0
 7e6:   c5 f9 58 d2             vaddpd %xmm2,%xmm0,%xmm2
 7ea:   c5 f9 57 c0             vxorpd %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
 7ee:   c5 e9 7c d2             vhaddpd %xmm2,%xmm2,%xmm2
 7f2:   c5 fb 58 d2             vaddsd %xmm2,%xmm0,%xmm2
 7f6:   c5 f9 28 c2             vmovapd %xmm2,%xmm0
 7fa:   c5 f8 77                vzeroupper 
 7fd:   c3                      retq   
 7fe:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 800:   c5 e9 57 d2             vxorpd %xmm2,%xmm2,%xmm2
 804:   eb da                   jmp    7e0 <ddot+0x50>
 806:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 80d:   00 00 00
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] of your code and compiler options, or better the asm for the loop you actually measured, so we can see if there is really only the one `...pd ymm` math instruction.  You aren't doing a horizontal sum at the end, are you, to actually get the scalar result?  Or maybe you are, and that's the 128 and scalar.  Did you use `_mm256_hadd_pd` or something?

Comment: I added the MCVE. I do a horizontal sum, but not a `256` one.

Comment: Your `ddot4` runs `_mm256_add_pd(v_dot0, v_dot1);` at the start of the cleanup, and since you call it with size=4, you get the cleanup once per FMA.  Note that your `v_dot1` is always zero, so this is pointless, but the CPU doesn't know that.  My guess was wrong, it's not a 256-bit hadd, it's just a useless 256-bit vertical add.  I think the final `_mm_add_sd(u_dot0, u_tmp);` is actually a bug: you've already added the last pair of elements with an inefficient 128-bit hadd, so this double-counts the lowest element.

Comment: See [Get sum of values stored in \_\_m256d with SSE/AVX](//stackoverflow.com/q/49941645) for a way that doesn't suck.

Comment: @PeterCordes: please be nice. Thank you for your comment though, I missed that additional `add`. You're right, there was actually code for unrolling with 8 vectors, but I deleted that for the minimal example. Note that this isn't my code, I'm just trying to understand code that someone else wrote.

Comment: Inefficient horizontal sums using `hadd` are a pet peeve of mine.  But anyway, I've written code that sucks, which I only later realized.  It doesn't make you a bad person, and I'm only saying the *code* sucks.  That's basically an objective fact.  Being cut down for a MCVE explains it `v_dot1`, though; like I said in an update to my answer you'd definitely want an unrolled version, so it's good that you already have one.  But I may have been a little hostile after seeing the apparent bug from `add_sd`; that just makes no sense (given this context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested with an asm loop on SKL.  An FMA instructions like `vfmadd231pd   ymm0, ymm1, ymm3` counts for 2 counts of `fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_double`, even though it's a single uop!

**I guess Intel really wanted a FLOP counter, not an instruction or uop counter.**

Your 3rd 256-bit FP uop is probably coming from something else you're doing, like a horizontal sum that starts out doing a 256-bit shuffle and another 256-bit add, instead of reducing to 128-bit first.  I hope you're not using `_mm256_hadd_pd`!

---

Test code inner loop:

```
$ asm-link -d -n "testloop.asm"  # assemble with NASM -felf64 and link with ld into a static binary

    mov     ebp, 100000000    # setup stuff outside the loop
    vzeroupper

0000000000401040 <_start.loop>:
  401040:       c4 e2 f5 b8 c3          vfmadd231pd ymm0,ymm1,ymm3
  401045:       c4 e2 f5 b8 e3          vfmadd231pd ymm4,ymm1,ymm3
  40104a:       ff cd                   dec    ebp
  40104c:       75 f2                   jne    401040 <_start.loop>


$ taskset -c 3 perf stat -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,branches,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread,fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_double -r4 ./"$t"


 Performance counter stats for './testloop-cvtss2sd' (4 runs):

            102.67 msec task-clock                #    0.999 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.00% )
                 2      context-switches          #   24.510 M/sec                    ( +- 20.00% )
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
                 2      page-faults               #   22.059 M/sec                    ( +- 11.11% )
       400,388,898      cycles                    # 3925381.355 GHz                   ( +-  0.00% )
       100,050,708      branches                  # 980889291.667 M/sec               ( +-  0.00% )
       400,256,258      instructions              #    1.00  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.00% )
       300,377,737      uops_issued.any           # 2944879772.059 M/sec              ( +-  0.00% )
       300,389,230      uops_executed.thread      # 2944992450.980 M/sec              ( +-  0.00% )
       400,000,000      fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_double # 3921568627.451 M/sec            

         0.1028042 +- 0.0000170 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  0.02% )
```

**400M counts of `fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_double` for 200M FMA instructions / 100M loop iterations.**

(IDK what up with `perf` 4.20.g8fe28c + kernel `4.20.3-arch1-1-ARCH`.  They calculate per-second stuff with the decimal in the wrong place for the unit.  e.g. 3925381.355 kHz is correct, not GHz.  Not sure if it's a bug in perf or the kernel.

Without vzeroupper, I'd sometimes see a latency of 5 cycles, not 4, for FMA.  IDK if the kernel left a register in a polluted state or something.

---

> Why do I get three though, and not two? (see MCVE added to original post)

**Your `ddot4` runs `_mm256_add_pd(v_dot0, v_dot1);` at the start of the cleanup**, and since you call it with size=4, you get the cleanup once per FMA.

Note that your `v_dot1` is always zero (because you didn't actually unroll with 2 accumulators like you're planning to?)  So this is pointless, but the CPU doesn't know that.  My guess was wrong, it's not a 256-bit hadd, it's just a useless 256-bit vertical add.

(**For larger vectors, yes multiple accumulators are *very* valuable to hide FMA latency.  You'll want at least 8 vectors**.  See [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction) for more about unrolling with multiple accumulators.  But then you'll want a cleanup loop that does 1 vector at a time until you're down to the last up-to-3 elements.)

Also, I think your final `_mm_add_sd(u_dot0, u_tmp);` is actually a bug: you've already added the last pair of elements with an inefficient 128-bit hadd, so this double-counts the lowest element.

See [Get sum of values stored in __m256d with SSE/AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49941645) for a way that doesn't suck.

---

Also note that GCC is splitting your unaligned loads into 128-bit halves with `vinsertf128` because you compiled with the default `-mtune=generic` (which favours Sandybridge) instead of using `-march=haswell` to enable AVX+FMA and set `-mtune=haswell`.  (Or use `-march=native`)

Comment: Thanks for checking that. So we're on the same page that one `256b_packed_double` doesn't map to one `vfmadd231pd`. Why do I get three though, and not two? (see MCVE added to original post)

Comment: thanks for the hint on compiler flags. I did add `-mavx2` and `-mfma` but apparently that was not enough.

Comment: @Nibor: it's enough to enable those instruction sets, but not to actually tune for a CPU that has them. :P  See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80568 and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78762 for a feature-request to have `-mavx2` set tuning options for CPUs that can run the code, like a `tune=generic-avx2` if such a thing existed.

Comment: The `perf stat` rates bug was fixed in https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/1025968/

Comment: @Zulan: Thanks, hopefully Arch Linux will update their perf package soon.  Kinda disappointed that a month old super-obviously-visible bug (for anyone who uses `perf stat` anyway) is still unfixed in the Arch repos :/