# How to chain avx2 intrinsics efficiently to perform chain of arithmetic operations?

Tags: gcc, optimization, vectorization, intrinsics, avx2

I wrote a large program to simulate molecular system. I ran it on a desktop computer whose processor is a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz. Most of the time (75%) is used to calculate a Lennard Jones potential on 4 neighbours.

To optimize it, I am learning how to use `avx2 intrinsics` and I wrote a simplified version that performs only the LJ calculation : `(d_eq/d_cur)**12 - 2.0*(d_eq/d_cur)**6`

This is the code without the intrinsics :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

double lj_pot(double* d_cur) {
    const double d_eq = 1.0;
    double ratio, vpot1, eie;
        
    eie =0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        ratio = d_eq/d_cur[i] ;
        vpot1 = ratio*ratio*ratio ;
        vpot1 = vpot1*vpot1 ;
        eie += vpot1*(vpot1-2.0);
    }
    
    return eie;
}

int main()
{
    double d_cur[4];
    double eee;
    
    eee=0.0;
    
    for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            d_cur[j] = 0.5+(double)(rand()) / (double)(RAND_MAX); // between 0.5 , 1.5
        }
        eee += lj_pot(d_cur);
    }
    printf("%f\n",eee);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the code with the AVX2 intrinsics

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

static inline double hsum_double_avx(__m256d v) {
// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/49943540/7462275
    __m128d vlow  = _mm256_castpd256_pd128(v);
    __m128d vhigh = _mm256_extractf128_pd(v, 1); // high 128
            vlow  = _mm_add_pd(vlow, vhigh);     // reduce down to 128

    __m128d high64 = _mm_unpackhi_pd(vlow, vlow);
    return  _mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm_add_sd(vlow, high64));  // reduce to scalar
}

double lj_pot(double* d_cur) {
    
    
    const __m256d d_eq = _mm256_set1_pd(1.0);
    const __m256d two_dbl = _mm256_set1_pd(2.0);
    __m256d vec1, vec2;
        
    vec1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(d_cur);
    vec1 = _mm256_div_pd(d_eq,vec1);
    vec2 = _mm256_mul_pd(vec1,vec1); // (d_eq/d_cur)**2
    vec1 = _mm256_mul_pd(vec2,vec2); // (d_eq/d_cur)**4
    vec1 = _mm256_mul_pd(vec1,vec2); // (d_eq/d_cur)**6
    vec2 = _mm256_sub_pd(vec1,two_dbl); // (d_eq/d_cur)**6 - 2.0
    vec1 = _mm256_mul_pd(vec1,vec2); // (d_eq/d_cur)**12 -2.0*(d_eq/d_cur)**6

    return hsum_double_avx(vec1);
}

int main()
{
    double d_cur[4];
    double eee;
    
    eee=0.0;
    

    
    for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            d_cur[j] = 0.5+(double)(rand()) / (double)(RAND_MAX); // between 0.5 , 1.5
        }
        eee += lj_pot(d_cur);
    }
    printf("%f\n",eee);
    return 0;
}
```

This code output the same result than the first one. But it is slower.
(`gcc -O3 -mavx -o lj_pot lj_pot.c` is used to compile both programs.)

When I inspect the assembly code, I suppose (perhaps it is not the good reason) I do not use the AVX2 intrinsics correctly to perform chain of arithmetic operations. What must I change to have a program faster ?

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC automatically uses SIMD for your original code.  Your hand-optimization is just inhibiting the compiler's optimization.  Check out the [resulting assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/Ezf3ecEbs) with `-O3 -march=skylake -funsafe-math-optimizations`:

```
lj_pot(double*):
    vbroadcastsd    ymm1, QWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
    vdivpd  ymm1, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]
    vmulpd  ymm0, ymm1, ymm1
    vmulpd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
    vbroadcastsd    ymm1, QWORD PTR .LC3[rip]
    vmulpd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm0
    vaddpd  ymm1, ymm0, ymm1
    vmulpd  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
    vextractf128    xmm1, ymm0, 0x1
    vaddpd  xmm1, xmm1, xmm0
    vunpckhpd       xmm0, xmm1, xmm1
    vaddpd  xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
    vzeroupper
    ret
```

If you want to optimize this, start by looking at what the compiler is doing.  It is pretty smart.

Comment: Do you know why the compiler does not use FMA instructions here? AFAIK, they are available on Skylake and faster than doing separate mul+add.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Best I know, `-ffp-contract=fast` (which would provide for such FMA contraction) is part of `-ffast-math` but not part of `-funsafe-math-optimizations`.

Comment: Ok. `-ffast-math` does not seems to improve this. Clang also does the same thing so it may not be just because of a missed optimization. Strange.

Comment: @JérômeRichard That *is* strange. One more reason to code `_mm256_fmadd_ps` directly.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Weird.  `-ffp-contract=fast` is actually on by default in GCC (unless you use `-std=c11` instead of the default `gnu11`). See https://godbolt.org/z/s7n7d1Gq1 for proof with a simple function that just does `a*b+c` as one or two statements.  In Clang the default fp-contract=on (which clang is able to support as separate from "fast", unlike GCC which probably loses the source information that the operations were part of the same expression vs. separate statements, so can only do `off` or `fast`.)  But `clang -fast-math` also doesn't contract this function.

Comment: @njuffa and Jérôme: Note that this function needs every product, so contracting to FMA wouldn't save total instructions; to feed the final `mul` of `vpot1*(vpot1-2.0)`, it would need an FMA and a mul (in parallel for the `vpot1*vpot1` squaring vs. `vpot1*vpot1 -2`) instead of a mul then add.  So it would be a latency win, but cost somewhat more power, and not be any better for throughput on Skylake assuming OoO exec can hide the latency.  (The accumulation into `eie +=...` is a horizontal sum, unless it extracted both operands early and did 128-bit mul + FMA?  But that would need 2 extracts).

Comment: It would be *worse* for throughput on Zen 3 and 4, which have 2x mul/FMA units on ports FP0,1, and 2x FP add units on ports FP2,3.  (https://uops.info/).  If the cost model isn't specialized for SKL vs. Zen3, this is actually the right decision for throughput (and power, thus turbo frequency).

Comment: @njuffa: As harold's answer points out, this 4-element function gets inlined into the caller in `main`.  But GCC gives `main` `__attribute__((cold))` by default, so it doesn't auto-vectorize there.  (Actually even renaming `main` to `foo` doesn't vectorize because of the scalar `rand()` call, according to `-fopt-info-vec-missed` https://godbolt.org/z/brb5r1a6x.)  But it *does* contract to scalar `vfmadd132sd` since now the `eie += vpot1 * (vpot1-2.0);` / `eee += lj_pot(d_cur);` fits the pattern for FMA

Comment: @John, Harold, Peter, Jerome, Njuffa. Thanks a lot for yours answer and comments even if I do not understand everything very well because of my low skill in assembly. Should I conclude that using C intrinsics is not a good idea to perform chain of arithmetic operation ? And the best to do is either to test compilation options or to code directly in assembly the critical part of the program ?

Comment: @Stef1611: SIMD intrinsics are good when you need them, but you should always check first what the compiler can do for you automatically.  As for "code directly in assembly," I would not suggest that.  I think you're operating under the assumption that "low level code is fast" which is not true.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note I think, that (at least [the way I compiled the source](https://godbolt.org/z/GbszbGcE7)), the stand-alone copy of `lj_pot` got auto-vectorized but not the inlined copy, which is the copy that actually runs. The stand-alone copy is not called from `main`. So auto-vectorization isn't really doing anything for you here, unless the assembly code that you got was qualitatively different from what happened when I compiled your program.

There are two non-ideal things that I noticed about the vectorized code:

- Random number generation is still done with scalars, which is already a noteworthy item by itself (though not by itself a regression) and also means that a vector will have to be assembled from scalars. Computing some scalars and then combining them into a vector is generally something to avoid. Storing scalars to memory and then doing a vector load (which is what happens in code) has a significant latency penalty (that perhaps should not be very important here, since that latency is not inside a loop-carried dependency chain) and using shuffles/inserts/etc to construct a vector without going through memory (this normally results from abusing the `_mm(256)_set_***` macros with non-constant arguments) costs a lot of instructions.
- Horizontal addition is performed 10000000 times inside that loop, instead of adding up vectors and performing one horizontal addition after the loop.

With both of those items improved, so with vectorized random number generation and horizontal sum after the main loop, resulting in essentially only vector arithmetic in the loop (well, and incrementing the loop counter), I expect that the code should become faster than it originally was.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. The 10000000 time loop is only there to have an execution time that I could measure with `time``. And I used a random number generation to have different values at each function call. Otherwise with constant values and O3 optimisation, the function is called only one time. I also add a comment in John's answer.

Comment: @Stef1611 OK, that changes a lot. Annoyingly this program ends up being an example of the time a function possibly depending on the context from which it is called (affecting the latency of the vector load for your vectorized code, affecting whether it gets vectorized at all or not when relying on auto-vectorization). So how you can write a test harness for timing that accurately reflects how the function would actually perform for real, depends on how it would be used for real. That also affects whether you should measure latency or throughput, which are commonly very different at this scale.

Comment: Perhaps, I was not clear enough in the introduction of my question. My initial aim was to optimize another program`(a large one). In this program, 75% of the time is used to calculate a LJ potential on 4 neigbourgs. I used `perf`to detect that. When I looked for a solution to optimize it, After reading many things, I decided to do all the 4 calculations at the same time and I used intrinsics because I found them very simple to use. I was very surprised by the difference in the execution time. So, I ask ed this question.

Comment: Have you seen my comment in the answer of John ? ... even if I do not understand everything very well because of my low skill in assembly. Should I conclude that using C intrinsics is not a good idea to perform chain of arithmetic operation ? And the best to do is either to test compilation options or to code directly in assembly the critical part of the program ?

Comment: @Stef1611 they're fine to use. Safer than relying on auto-vectorization, which is unreliable as this test accidentally also shows. Possibly easier to use than raw assembly (but that's debatable) but also calling raw assembly functions can prevent some compiler optimizations (the function won't be inlined, there is no constant propagation, etc). Of course the performance depends on exactly what the code is, so there isn't some big general statement to make about it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. First, I tried compiler explorer. Thanks a lot to make me discover it. It helps a lot to understand. Concerning, C intrinsics, for an assembly beginner, I could say that it is easier to use than assembly. I agree with the comment concerning the reliability of auto-vectorization. In this case, it works because it is simple. But in the real program, it does not work because there are other things in the 4 times loop. I am going to do some test. I could split the loop in two parts, .... I am sorry but I could not accept two answers.