# High Variance In Manual Vectorization Performance

Tags: c, performance, vectorization, avx2, fma

I am trying to manually vectorize the calculation of a dot product of two vectors. Please note that I am doing this as an exercise and I am aware that using a BLAS library would be more suitable. The issue is that on benchmarking my manually vectorized code, I am getting extremely high variance in the achieved performance (I run the benchmark 10,20,...,90 times and get statistics for each set of runs). If it is significant, I am running all benchmarks on WSL2 in Windows 10, running on a laptop with an AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS.

My code for manual vectorization is as below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

#define MATRIX_SIZE 1000

double matrix[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
double vector[MATRIX_SIZE];
double result[MATRIX_SIZE];

#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize("O0")
void initialize() {
    // Initialize matrix and vector with random values
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        }
        vector[i] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }
}
#pragma GCC pop_options

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941645/get-sum-of-values-stored-in-m256d-with-sse-avx
double hsum_double_avx(__m256d v) {
    __m128d vlow  = _mm256_castpd256_pd128(v);
    __m128d vhigh = _mm256_extractf128_pd(v, 1); // high 128
            vlow  = _mm_add_pd(vlow, vhigh);     // reduce down to 128

    __m128d high64 = _mm_unpackhi_pd(vlow, vlow);
    return  _mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm_add_sd(vlow, high64));  // reduce to scalar
}

double dot_product(double* vec1, double* vec2) {
    __m256d accum1 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d accum2 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d accum3 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d accum4 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d accum5 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d accum6 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d accum7 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d accum8 = _mm256_setzero_pd();

    double* stop_vec = vec1 + MATRIX_SIZE;

    while (vec1 + 32 <= stop_vec)
    {
        __m256d v11 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec1);
        __m256d v12 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec1+4);
        __m256d v13 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec1+8);
        __m256d v14 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec1+12);
        __m256d v15 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec1+16);
        __m256d v16 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec1+20);
        __m256d v17 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec1+24);
        __m256d v18 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec1+28);

        __m256d v21 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec2);
        __m256d v22 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec2+4);
        __m256d v23 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec2+8);
        __m256d v24 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec2+12);
        __m256d v25 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec2+16);
        __m256d v26 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec2+20);
        __m256d v27 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec2+24);
        __m256d v28 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vec2+28);

        accum1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v11, v21, accum1);
        accum2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v12, v22, accum2);
        accum3 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v13, v23, accum3);
        accum4 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v14, v24, accum4);
        accum5 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v11, v21, accum5);
        accum6 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v12, v22, accum6);
        accum7 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v13, v23, accum7);
        accum8 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v14, v24, accum8);

        vec1 += 32;
        vec2 += 32;
    }

    long long diff = stop_vec-vec1;
    diff -= 1;

    __m256i mask = _mm256_setr_epi64x(diff, diff-1, diff-2, diff-3);
    __m256d v11 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec1, mask);
    __m256d v21 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec2, mask);
    accum1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v11, v21, accum1);

    mask = _mm256_setr_epi64x(diff-4, diff-5, diff-6, diff-7);
    __m256d v12 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec1+4, mask);
    __m256d v22 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec2+4, mask);
    accum2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v12, v22, accum2);

    mask = _mm256_setr_epi64x(diff-8, diff-9, diff-10, diff-11);
    __m256d v13 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec1+8, mask);
    __m256d v23 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec2+8, mask);
    accum3 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v13, v23, accum3);

    mask = _mm256_setr_epi64x(diff-12, diff-13, diff-14, diff-15);
    __m256d v14 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec1+12, mask);
    __m256d v24 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec2+12, mask);
    accum4 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v14, v24, accum4);

    mask = _mm256_setr_epi64x(diff-16, diff-17, diff-18, diff-19);
    __m256d v15 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec1+16, mask);
    __m256d v25 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec2+16, mask);
    accum5 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v15, v25, accum5);

    mask = _mm256_setr_epi64x(diff-20, diff-21, diff-22, diff-23);
    __m256d v16 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec1+20, mask);
    __m256d v26 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec2+20, mask);
    accum6 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v16, v26, accum6);

    mask = _mm256_setr_epi64x(diff-24, diff-25, diff-26, diff-27);
    __m256d v17 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec1+24, mask);
    __m256d v27 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec2+24, mask);
    accum7 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v17, v27, accum7);

    mask = _mm256_setr_epi64x(diff-28, diff-29, diff-30, diff-31);
    __m256d v18 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec1+28, mask);
    __m256d v28 = _mm256_maskload_pd(vec2+28, mask);
    accum8 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v18, v28, accum8);

    accum1 = _mm256_add_pd(accum1, accum2);
    accum3 = _mm256_add_pd(accum3, accum4);
    accum5 = _mm256_add_pd(accum5, accum6);
    accum7 = _mm256_add_pd(accum7, accum8);
    accum1 = _mm256_add_pd(accum1, accum3);
    accum5 = _mm256_add_pd(accum5, accum7);
    accum1 = _mm256_add_pd(accum1, accum5);
    // accum1 = _mm256_add_pd(accum1, accum3);

    return hsum_double_avx(accum1);
}

// Auto dot product code
//void matrix_vector_multiply() {
    // Perform matrix-vector multiplication
//    for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
//        result[i] = 0.0;
//        for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++) {
//            result[i] += matrix[i][j] * vector[j];
//        }
//    }
//}

void matrix_vector_multiply() {
    // Perform matrix-vector multiplication
    for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
        result[i] += dot_product(matrix[i], vector);
    }
}

int main() {
    initialize();

    clock_t start_time = clock();
    matrix_vector_multiply();
    clock_t end_time = clock();
    double elapsed_time = ((double) (end_time - start_time)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    // Print time taken
    // printf("Time taken: %f seconds\n", elapsed_time);

    // Calculate total floating point operations
    long long flops = 2 * MATRIX_SIZE * MATRIX_SIZE;

    // Calculate GFLOPS
    double gflops = flops / (elapsed_time * 1e9);
    printf("%f\n", gflops);

    return 0;
}
```

I used `#pragma GCC push_options` to prevent GCC from shifting the dot product calculation into the initialize function (it was doing so on -O3 before I did this). I tried using both 4 accumulators and 8 accumulators and 8 accumulators works better for me. I compile with the command `gcc -O3 -march=native -mavx2 -mfma mat-vec-manual.c -o manual.o`. Below are the statistics for the automatic vectorization,

[image: Manual Vectorization Statistics]

For the automatic vectorization from GCC, I use the same code as above but use the commented out `matrix_vector_multiply()` function instead. I compile with the command `gcc -O3 -march=native -ftree-vectorize -funroll-loops -ffast-math -mavx2 -mfma mat-vec-auto.c -o auto.o`. Below are the statistics for the manual vectorization,
[image: Automatic Vectorization Statistics]

As you can see from the statistics, although there is significant increase in the performance of the code on using automatic vectorization, there is also a large increase in the variance. Inspecting the generated assembly code (gcc v11.4.0) shows me that vectorization is occurring as expected and the FMA instructions are being used as well.

I considered this may be occurring due to the arrays not being aligned to 32 bytes, but on changing the array declarations to,

```
double matrix[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE] __attribute__((aligned(32)));
double vector[MATRIX_SIZE] __attribute__((aligned(32)));
double result[MATRIX_SIZE];
```

and changing each call to `_mm256_loadu_pd` to `_mm256_load_pd` and running the benchmarks again, there is no noticeable change in the results.

What am I missing here? Or is this type of variance expected?

Comment: Are you doing multiple runs within the same binary (your code does not look like it does), or do you call the binary multiple times? I guess the latter could explain a high variance. If you call your function multiple times from your binary, try calling it much more times and see if the variance decreases.

Comment: [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) - CPU frequency warm-up to max turbo will be a factor for very short runs, unless you run the program back-to-back with a shell loop, or like `perf stat -r 10 ./a.out`.  And/or set the CPU frequency governor to "performance", if that does anything inside the VM used by WSL2.

Comment: @chtz I was doing the latter. Implementing the former reduces variance drastically. My guess is that this is most likely due to changes in the OS state when I call my binary several times. But I still don't understand why exactly that would cause such a drastic increase in variance. However, thanks for the help!

Comment: @PeterCordes I am running the program back to back in a python script. I would have used `perf` but it is currently not usable in WSL2. I'm not sure whether it is possible to set the frequency governor in WSL2, but I will try and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test function `matrix_vector_multiply` executes very quickly. On my i9-11950H, it finishes under 1 ms. To reduce your variance, you may want to execute the function in a loop (say 1000 iterations) and measure that.

You may also want to replace `clock()` with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` calls. On MSVC, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is 1000 and that is insufficient for testing one pass over the function. With OP's GCC, that value is likely higher.

Additionally, you could do a warmup just before the measured section. This would make sure that your CPU is not clocked down to save power. The warmup should take at least a few milliseconds.

I retested with the following and got more consistent results, between 13 and 17 GFlops (running Release without debugger).

```cpp
 constexpr int N = 1000;
 // warmup
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
     matrix_vector_multiply();

 // reset the dest array
 memset(result, 0, sizeof(double) * MATRIX_SIZE);

 auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 
 for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
     matrix_vector_multiply();

 auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 double elapsed_time = 1e-9 * (double)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
```

Comment: This reduces variance drastically for me as well. What I don't understand however is why it was so high in the first place. I understand that various OS related issues may cause changes in performance but why would performance change so drastically in between runs? Also, why is the variance for the automatically vectorized code generated by GCC so low in the first place? Thanks a lot for the help!