# Understanding a code-example from the Intel Intrinsics Guide

Tags: intel, sse, simd, intrinsics, avx

I am trying to learn what `_mm256_permute2f128_ps()` does, but can't fully understand the [intel's code-example](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_permute&expand=2436,2437,4172&techs=AVX).

```
DEFINE SELECT4(src1, src2, control) {
    CASE(control[1:0]) OF
    0:  tmp[127:0] := src1[127:0]
    1:  tmp[127:0] := src1[255:128]
    2:  tmp[127:0] := src2[127:0]
    3:  tmp[127:0] := src2[255:128]
    ESAC
    IF control[3]
        tmp[127:0] := 0
    FI
    RETURN tmp[127:0]
}
dst[127:0] := SELECT4(a[255:0], b[255:0], imm8[3:0])
dst[255:128] := SELECT4(a[255:0], b[255:0], imm8[7:4])
dst[MAX:256] := 0
```

Specifically, I don't understand:

- the `imm8[3:0]` notation.  Are they using it as a 4-byte mask?
  [But I've seen people invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9800444/9007125)  `_mm256_permute2f128_pd(myVec, myVec, 5)`, where imm8 is used as a number (number 5).
- Inside the `SELECT4` function, what does `control[1:0]` mean? Is control a byte-mask, or used as a number? How many bytes is it made of?
- why `IF control[3]` is used in intel's example. Doesn't it undo the choice `3:` inside `CASE`?  Why would we ever want to set `tmp[127 to 0]` to zero, if we've been outputting into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[x:y]` notations always refers to bitnumbers in this case. E.g., if you pass 5 as the `imm8` argument, then (because `5==0b00000101`) `imm8[3:0]==0b0101==5` and if that was passed as `control` to the `SELECT4` macro, you would get `control[3]==0==false` and `control[1:0]==0b01==1`. The `control[2]` bit would be ignored.

Fully evaluating this, you get

```
dst[127:0]   := SELECT4(a[255:0], b[255:0], 5) == a[255:128]
dst[255:128] := SELECT4(a[255:0], b[255:0], 0) == a[127:0]
```

That means this would switch the upper and lower half of the `a` register and store it into the `dst` register.

The `dst[MAX:256] := 0` is only relevant for architectures with larger registers (if you have AVX-512), i.e., it sets everything above bit 255 to zero. This is in contrast to legacy SSE instructions, which (if executed on CPUs with AVX-support) would leave the upper half unchanged (and producing false dependencies -- see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839925/using-avx-cpu-instructions-poor-performance-without-archavx)).